# Benefit of replacing the middle man?

Tags: blockchain

It seems like instead of paying to the middle man, blockchain offers to pay the transaction fee to the nodes (it is not clear which one is bigger). Thus, there is not much benefit money-wise. Is the benefit only in security (even if one of the nodes is hacked, the ledger is still secure because it is stored on other nodes)?